# Duplicate Files Copied-Bouncy Castle(bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar)-How can I resolve that?

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I'm getting this annoying message(full message at the bottom at the message),and I have no idea which libraries include those bouncycastle files (I didn't include them myself directly),I'm guessing that two of them include different versions of the same files? :P

How can I know which packages/libraries included those? How can I solve the issue?

Here are the build.grade files:

App level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dor.only.dorking.android.profilemanager"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-plus:v1-rev375-1.21.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-beta3'
}
```

Project level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-beta3'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the error message (Gradle's output, I am using Android Studio):

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/BCKEY.DSA
    File1: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.48\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
    File2: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.48\bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar

Comment: a late answer, but did you try listing out the dependency tree and identifying the duplicate bcpkix-jdk15on dependencies?

Comment: No,I think that was a glitch with some Android studio update (with a later update which came out later everything works fine), but for my future reference I will thank you if you can refer me to a resource which shows me how to list out the dependency tree :)

Comment: Sure - `./gradlew :app:dependencies` will print the dependency tree for the `app` subproject